# Ubuntu Private print

Tags: networking, drivers, printing

struggling here to use a specific print function " private print " in our network environment with Ubuntu.

We have private print enabled in all our users on our network, windows and MacOSX users without problems, everyone got a 4-digit code to be entered to the printer to make the Job print successful.

On Ubuntu it seems to be different, I cannot find any option to enable this function, here are some details :

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Laser printer Kyocera TaskAlfa 3511i Kyocera PPD installed correctly Cups configuration seems ok

Tried to search for printer configuration options on cups web page on localhost:631 no luck

Maybe it's a driver issue? Is there any third party linux software that con manage private print ?

Thank you in advance Simone